# Liferay multilingual support

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Is there any way to put custom fields attributes for users and organizations in details?

If so, how to make text field for custom fields to accept nonunicode "Arabic"?

I have added a new custom field "text field Arabic name". I want to add custom field in details of the form "organization information".

Comment: can you elaborate on "nonunicode arabic"? Custom Fields should accept anything that's UTF-8 encodable. I always assumed that arabic characters would be among these.

Comment: thank then what about part 2 ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking for. Could you add some more information to your question? e.g. what did you do, what do you want to achieve. Give samples

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your question correctly, this doesn't have a lot to do with multilingual features: If you create a custom field for an organization, but want to show this not under "Custom Fields" but under a section that makes more "business" sense (e.g. "Org. Information), you can easily do this.

A high-level sample is documented in the [Liferay Wiki](https://www.liferay.com/de/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Custom+Fields+and+JSP+Hooks), but with the title of that Wiki I found many other hits on the web, explaining how to override Liferay's UI with custom fields. This is also an exercise that's done through [Liferay Developer Training](https://www.liferay.com/services/training/topics/developer-training) (it's done for users there, but the same technique works for organizations).